# Hashtag, prevent raw URLs

Tags: jquery, hashtag

I´m working on a site with AJAX content loaded. To display this content I have created a div container in my index.html page where I load using .load jQuery method other html pages like sections or projects.

My problem is that I´m generating URLs like this:

This links load correctly the new contents and they generate a URL like this one:

http://domain.com/#dummy.html

The problem is that if you erase the hashtag from the URL and load that URL the site displays the dummy.html instead the index and the content loaded via AJAX.

I use hashtag change event to catch this changes in order to fire other effects in the page.

How could I fix this issue? There is some method to force to add the hashtag always a URL is requested?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is logical and not related to technology at hand.

Use `http://domain.com/#dummy-div` and make internal translation from dummy-div into dummy.html

Just decide on naming rules, and what should happen if user opens `http://domain.com/dummy-div`